# How to use the Navigation Drawer to switch Activities[Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I created an Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio 1.4. My Main Activity is already setted up and now I want to switch to another Activity via the Navigation Drawer. The second Activity (AddDataActivity) should collect some User Unputs to create string which should be displayed in my Main Activities ListView.
My problem is, that I dont know how to open the AddDataActivity without "loosing" my navigation Drawer.

```
Intent AddData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddDataActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(AddData);
```

Do I have to copy the whole Drawer Code for each Activity? Or would it be better to use Fragments?

Comment: *Or would it be better to use Fragments?* yes

Comment: So I have to replace the AddDataActivity with a AddData Fragment and call the Fragment in my MainActivity? - Just for me to get this right :P

Comment: Basically the activity will be a container for fragments, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Fragments now I avoid this Situation.

```js
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         Fragment fragment;
         FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragment = new ListViewFragment();
         int id = item.getItemId();

             if (id == R.id.nav_listview) {
                 fragment= new ListViewFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_add_data) {
                 fragment= new AddDataFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
                 fragment= new SettingsFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_rooms) {
                 fragment= new SavedRoomsFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_legal_information) {
                 fragment = new LegalInformationFragment();
             }
         ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();

         DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
         return true;
     }
```